# What do these asterisks on my map mean?

Tags: creature-in-the-well

As I explore, my map gets filled in with rooms and hallways as you'd expect. But sometimes after I leave a room I see the dot on the map has been filled with an asterisk:

[image: map view]

It sorta seems to indicate a room being completed, but I don't see it on rooms where I'm pretty confident I've lit all the bumpers.

What does this sign mean?

Answer (score 1):

This is simple, it is to indicate that you have directly interacted with the door, etc.